# gcc linker giant bin file

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I was using and old verison of ARM official develop environment RVDS, and currently i'd like to switch to linux gcc tool chain.

So i'd like to write a simple hello world to run on our own board, print from UART. but the linker and objcopy stuck me.

here is my LD file:

```
MEMORY
{
  rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 128K
  ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x0;
    .text : {
        *(vectors)
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
    }
    . = 0x60000000;

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

after make, it will generate a giant bin file about 1.6G, which is just the size of 0x60000000.

how can I fix this problem? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the giant file is gone when i changed to these compiler settings:

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
OBJCP = arm-none-eabi-objcopy

CFLAGS += -mcpu=arm1176jz-s -mthumb -mlittle-endian
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
CFLAGS += -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -Wall -std=c99

LFLAGS += -nostartfiles
LFLAGS += -T my_ld.ld

CPFLAGS = -O binary
```

Answer (score 2):

The data section should be located in the RAM. Change your linker script:

```
/*  . = 0x60000000; removed */

.data : {
    *(.data)
} >RAM

.bss : {
    *(.bss)
} >RAM
```

Your startup code should copy the data from the ROM to the RAM. For that purpose it needs the addresses of the initialization values and where your data should be present at runtime.

Change your script again:

```
/* used by the startup to initialize data */
_sidata = .;

.data : AT( _sidata )
{
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    _edata = .;
} >RAM

.bss : {
    _sbss = .;
    *(.bss)
    _ebss = .;
} >RAM
```

Add code

```
/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
  movs  r1, #0
  b  LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr  r3, =_sidata
  ldr  r3, [r3, r1]
  str  r3, [r0, r1]
  adds  r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr  r0, =_sdata
  ldr  r3, =_edata
  adds  r2, r0, r1
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  CopyDataInit
```

Add similar code for the `.bss` section.

```
  ldr  r2, =_sbss
  b  LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */
FillZerobss:
  movs  r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2], #4

LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr  r3, = _ebss
  cmp  r2, r3
  bcc  FillZerobss
```

Comment: thank you, i changed the ld and objcopy parameters and the problem is gone, though i didn't change the ld file. but your suggestion pushed me to think hard the relationship between the ld file and the makefile.

Comment: I recommend that you add your own answer to the question. You should describe *what*  parameters you used and how this helps. The Stack Overflow question are read be many users. (This question has been viewed 17 times until now.)

Comment: thanks, i think the 17 times have at least 10 times my own contribution, i'll answer it now :)